# Jenkins Artifactory plugin publishes only one part of multiproject repository

Tags: gradle, jenkins, artifactory

first question here, so please go easy on me. :)

I am in the process of upgrading our companies Jenkins server. During that I am also upgrading the different plugins we are using.
The first project I am migrating to the new Jenkins contains a repository with 2 Java services inside. One depends on the other to be build. We are using Gradle as a build tool. On the old Jenkins with old plugins this works pretty well.
On the new Jenkins, both services are built but only one of them gets actually published to our Artifactory. And I cant find out why that is the case. What I found though, is that when I downgrade the Artifactory plugin to the old version, it will work properly. Build both services, and also publish both of them to artifactory.
Does anyone know what could be causing this? Are there changes to the Artifactory plugin that could be the reason?

|  | Old Versions: | New Versions: |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jenkins | 2.190.1 | 2.387.3 |
| Artifactory Plugin | 3.9.0 | 3.18.1 |
| Gradle | 8.2.1 | 8.2.1 |

I enabled logging for the artifactoryPublish task on both old and new Jenkins and tried to find differences in the logs but from what I can tell, there are no significant differences.
And as mentioned above, I downgraded the Artifactory plugin to the old version, and with that it worked again as expected.

Below find all the config files, that I think may be relevant. If there are others you might need just let me know.

**Jenkinsfile**

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '10'))
        skipStagesAfterUnstable()
    }
    tools {
        jdk "Temurin 17"      
    }
    environment {
        sonarProjectName = "jenkins-migration-test-service"
        sonarBaseFolder = "jenkins-migration-test-service/"

        REVISION = getRevision()
        GRADLE_OPTS = '-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Artifactory Configuration') {
            steps {
              sh "echo Revision = ${getRevision()}"
              sh "echo Repository =  ${getRepository()}"
                defineArtifactory()
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    dir("kids-service/src/main/resources") {
                        sh "echo '\ninfo.build.version=${REVISION}\n' >> application.properties"
                        sh "echo 'eureka.instance.metadata-map.release-version=${REVISION}\n' >> application.properties"
                    }
                }
                runGradleTask("clean build test")
            }
            post {
                always {
                    archiveArtifacts artifacts: "**/build/libs/*.jar", fingerprint: true
                    lastChanges since: "PREVIOUS_REVISION", format: "SIDE", matching: "LINE"
                    junit "**/build/test-results/**/*.xml"
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Publish Artifacts") {
            when { branch "master" }
            steps {
                 script {
                    sshagent(["***************"]) {
                        sh "git tag ${REVISION}"
                        sh "git push --tags"
                    }
                } 
                runGradleTask("artifactoryPublish")
            }
        }
        stage("Publish Build Information") {
            when { branch "master" }
            steps {
                rtPublishBuildInfo(
                        serverId: "98747153@1401865198163"
                )
            }
        }
        stage("Deploy on dev") {
            when { branch "master" }
            steps {
                build job: '/deploy-backend', parameters: [
                        string(name: 'service_host', value: 'service-host'),
                        string(name: 'service_name', value: 'kids-service'),
                        string(name: 'service_version', value: "${REVISION}"),
                        string(name: 'health_check_port', value: "48202")
                ], wait: true, propagate: true, quietPeriod: 0
            }
        }
    }
}

def getRevision() {
    def apiVersion = "0.1"
    def patchNumber = "1339"
    def branchName = "${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
    def serviceName = "jenkins-migration-test-service"
  
    if (branchName == "master") {
        return apiVersion + "." + patchNumber
    }
    else {
        return apiVersion + "." + branchName + "." + patchNumber + "-SNAPSHOT"
    }
}

void runGradleTask(String tasks) {
    rtGradleRun(
            tool: 'gradle',
            rootDir: './',
            useWrapper: true,
            buildFile: "build.gradle.kts",
            tasks: tasks,
            deployerId: 'GRADLE_DEPLOYER',
            resolverId: 'GRADLE_RESOLVER',
            switches: '-Pversion=${REVISION} --warning-mode all'
    )
}

void runGradleTaskWithDebug(String tasks) {
    rtGradleRun(
            tool: 'gradle',
            rootDir: './',
            useWrapper: true,
            buildFile: "build.gradle.kts",
            tasks: tasks,
            deployerId: 'GRADLE_DEPLOYER',
            resolverId: 'GRADLE_RESOLVER',
            switches: '-Pversion=${REVISION} --warning-mode all --debug'
    )
}
void defineArtifactory() {
    rtGradleDeployer(
            id: 'GRADLE_DEPLOYER',
            serverId: '98747153@1401865198163',
            deployIvyDescriptors: true,
            deployMavenDescriptors: true,
            ivyPattern: '[organisation]/[module]/ivy-[revision].xml',
            artifactPattern: '[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]',
            repo: getRepository()
    )

    rtGradleResolver(
            id: 'GRADLE_RESOLVER',
            serverId: '98747153@1401865198163'
    )

    rtBuildInfo(
            captureEnv: true,
            includeEnvPatterns: ["*"]
    )
}

def getRepository() {
    def branchName = "${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
    if (branchName == "master") {
        return "libs-release-local"
    } else {
        return "libs-snapshot-local"
    }
}
```

**Parent project build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
    id("maven-publish")
    id("com.diffplug.spotless") version "6.22.0"
    id("io.freefair.lombok") version "8.4" apply false
}

allprojects {
    apply(plugin = "com.diffplug.spotless")

    group = "de.********"

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url = uri("https://artifactory.********.***/artifactory/vrepo") }
    }

    spotless {
        format("misc") {
            target("*.md", ".gitignore")
            trimTrailingWhitespace()
            indentWithSpaces()
            endWithNewline()
        }
        kotlinGradle {
            target("*.kts")
            ktlint()
        }
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply(plugin = "java")
    apply(plugin = "maven-publish")
    apply(plugin = "com.diffplug.spotless")
    apply(plugin = "io.freefair.lombok")

    spotless {
        java {
            googleJavaFormat()
        }
    }

    publishing {
        publications {
            create<MavenPublication>("maven") {
                from(components["java"])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Parent project settings.gradle.kts**

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url = uri("https://artifactory.********.***/artifactory/gradle-plugins-remote/") }
    }
}

rootProject.name = "kids-service-parent"
include("kids-service-api", "kids-service")
```

**kids-service build.gradle.kts** --> this one doesnt get published

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.5"
    id("jacoco")
    id("org.sonarqube") version "4.4.1.3373"
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    withSourcesJar()
}

sonar {
    properties {
        property("sonar.projectKey", "de.***********:kids-service")
        property("sonar.projectName", "kids-service")
        property("sonar.coverage.exclusions", "**/mock/**")
    }
}

springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.8"
}

dependencies {
    implementation(platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:3.1.5"))
    implementation(platform("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2022.0.4"))

    implementation(project(":kids-service-api"))
    implementation("de.***********.lib:cps-rest-lib-all:0.1.9")

    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client")
    implementation("net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:7.4")
    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core")
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.2.0")
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api:2.2.0")

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
    testRuntimeOnly("com.h2database:h2")

    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
}

tasks.bootJar {
    launchScript()
}

tasks.jar {
    enabled = false
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    finalizedBy(tasks.jacocoTestReport)
}

tasks.jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn(tasks.test)
    reports {
        xml.required.set(true)
    }
}

configurations {
    arrayOf(apiElements, runtimeElements).forEach {
        it.get().outgoing.artifact(tasks.bootJar)
    }
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom(configurations.annotationProcessor.get())
    }
}
```

**kids-service-api build.gradle.kts** --> this one gets published

```
plugins {
    id("java-library")
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.5"
}

tasks.bootJar {
    enabled = false
}

tasks.jar {
    enabled = true
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    withSourcesJar()
    withJavadocJar()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:3.1.5"))

    api(""de.***********.lib:cps-rest-lib-models:0.1.9")

    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.2.0")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")

    compileOnly("com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2")
}
```

Comment: Why don't use JFrog CLI as tools in Jenkins?

Comment: Hmn, to be honest, I didnt think about changing tools at all. Mainly because introducing new tools is kind of complicated in my company for security/compliance reasons. 
Why would you suggest using JFrog CLI?